# How to set a URL for the top level of a Structure section?

Tags: structure, url

I have entries in a structure section. I'd like the users to view the list of entries without the entries themselves being assigned URLs.

How can I set a URL for the top level of a Structure section without enabling "Entry URL Format"?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're asking—it sounds like you can just disable URLs for that section, and create a template that will get loaded at the URL you want.

For example, if you had a *Section* called “Plants,” and you wanted to list all plants at mywebsite.com/plants, you could just create `craft/templates/plants.twig`:

```html
{% set plants = craft.entries({ section: 'plants', limit: null }).find %}

<ul>
  {% for plant in plants %}
    <li>{{ plant.title }}</li>
  {% endear %}
</ul>
```

If you need to edit anything on that page, you'll need to create another entry (probably a *Single*) to manage that content.

Answer (score 0):

A section in Craft (regardless of it is a Single, Channel or Structure section) is defined by a combination of your Craft Site URL (defined under `Settings->General` or overwritten via https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#siteUrl) and that section's "Entry URL Format" under the section's settings (`Settings->Sections->(your structure section)->Entry URL Format`).

You can read more about them here: https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries

Comment: Thanks! I got a bit stuck poking around there. I was trying to find a way to do with without the entries getting a URL. I forgot that detail in the question. The demo site had a location Structure embedded in a Single that I was literally just now trying to emulate.

Comment: Actually, you answered the question I posed, but it wasn't the one I meant to ask. Would it be best to un-edit my question and accept your answer for posterity, then ask the question I meant to?

Comment: Probably best just to post a new question and leave this one here for posterity.